# Closed form for integral of inverse hyperbolic function in terms of ${_4F_3}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

While attempting to evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sinh^{-1}{\left(\sqrt{\sin{x}}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x$, I stumbled upon the following representation for a related integral in terms of hypergeometric functions:

> $$\small{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\sinh^{-1}{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac34\right)}^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,{_4F_3}{\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac34,\frac34;\frac12,\frac54,\frac54;1\right)}-\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}^2}{72\sqrt{2\pi}}{_4F_3}{\left(\frac34,\frac34,\frac54,\frac54;\frac32,\frac74,\frac74;1\right)}}.$$

I'm having some trouble wading through the algebraic muckity-muck, so I'd like help confirming the above conjectured identity. More importantly, can these hypergeometrics be simplified in any significant way? The "niceness" of the parameters really makes me suspect it can be...

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: [***Hint***](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JYVeu.png).

Comment: @Lucian I thank you for that, but I seem to be missing something. How is there a nonzero imaginary component?

Comment: There isn't. :-$)$ The factor of *i* vanishes, and the answer is simply $\dfrac\pi2\ln2$.

Comment: Apparently, $~\text{Li}_2\bigg[\dfrac{1-\sqrt2}2\bigg]+\text{Li}_2\bigg[\Big(1-\sqrt2\Big)^2\bigg]+\dfrac12\cdot\ln^2\bigg[\dfrac{1+\sqrt2}2\bigg]=0,~$ which is what one gets after simplifying the expression in question.

Comment: @Lucian Doh! That probably confirms my suspicions that there's a vastly more elegant way to go about this problem lurking. Thanks again.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct, both sides being equal with each other, and with $\dfrac\pi4\ln2$.

Comment: I am very close to a proof and will post an answer when I have finished it.

Comment: @user111187 No, your response below was quite satisfactory. To be honest, I simply forget about this question amidst holiday activities. Oops :)

Comment: If you're watching this question, you may be interested in a recent similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395145

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$
\newcommand{\as}{\sinh^{-1}}
\newcommand{\at}{\tan^{-1}}
\begin{align}
I &:= 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x \as x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}
\\&= \int_0^{\pi/2} \as\sqrt{ \sin x } 
\\&= \frac 1 2\int_0^{\pi} \as\sqrt{ \sin x } 
\\&= \frac 1 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2}{1+t^2}\as\sqrt{ \frac{2t}{1+t^2}} 
\\&= \left.\at x \as\sqrt{ \frac{2t}{1+t^2}}\right\lvert _0^\infty - \int_0^{\infty} \at t \frac{1-t^2}{\sqrt{2t}(1+t^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}} 
\\&= \int_0^{\infty} \at t \frac{t-1}{\sqrt{2t}(1+t^2)} 
\\&= \sqrt 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2-1}{1+x^4}  \at x^2
\end{align}
$$

Let
$$
J(a) = \sqrt 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2-1}{1+x^4}  \log(1+ a^2 x^2),
$$
so $J(0) = 0$ and
$$
\begin{align}
J'(a) &= \sqrt 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2-1}{1+x^4}  \frac{2a x^2}{1+a^2x^2}
\\&= \sqrt 2\int_0^{\infty} \frac{2 \left(a^3 x^2-a^3-a x^2-a\right)}{\left(a^4+1\right) \left(x^4+1\right)}+\frac{2 a \left(a^2+1\right)}{\left(a^4+1\right) \left(a^2 x^2+1\right)}
\\&= \frac{ \pi\sqrt{2} }{a^2+\sqrt{2} a+1}
\\&= i \pi \left[\frac{1}{a+ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}}-\frac{1}{a+\frac{1-i}{\sqrt 2}} \right].
\end{align}
$$
This implies
$$
J\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}\right) = i \pi\left[\log\left(\sqrt 2 (1+i) \right) - \log \sqrt 2 \right],
$$
whence
$$
\boxed{
I = \operatorname{Im} J\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}\right) = \frac \pi 2 \log 2.}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sinh^{-1}(\sqrt{\sin x}) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\frac{{(\sin x)}^{(2n+1)/2}}{2n+1}$$
so the integral is equivalent to
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(2n+1)}\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{(2n+1)/2}\,dx$$
You have
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin x)^{(2n+1)/2}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2n+3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2n+5}{4}\right)}$$
(I haven't done the work myself, but I've seen the derivation somewhere...) Now it suffices to show that
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2(2n+1)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2n+3}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{2n+5}{4}\right)}=\sqrt\pi\ln2$$

Comment: It should be $\frac{2n+5}{4}$ instead of $\frac{2n+3}{5}$.

Comment: Ah I copied it incorrectly, it's actually $\dfrac{2n+5}{4}$ but I wouldn't know for certain, I didn't derive it myself

Comment: It is proven using the Beta function identity $$\int_0^{\pi/2} dx 2 \sin^{2a+1}x \cos^{2b+1} x = B(a,b)$$ The trouble with this approach is that evaluating the sum is not trivial at all (the sum is basically identical to the hypergeometric function expression)

Comment: Ah yes I do recall the Beta function being mentioned but I was and still am relatively unfamiliar with it.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.2121.pdf This can help

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I'll be sure to give it a read. And that's a shame about this approach, I was hoping it would work out nicely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19932/discussion-between-user111187-and-user170231).